# Getting a rank from a SQL total column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table like so...

```
ID | NAME  | RANK | PTS
---+-------+------+----
12 | John  | 1    | 28
18 | Andy  | 2    | 31
23 | Brian | 3    | 16
41 | Mike  | 4    | 33
15 | Jack  | 5    | 35
68 | Anne  | 6    | 24
```

I currently sort by...

```
SELECT * FROM `ranks` ORDER BY PTS desc
```

I am looking for some code that I can give it an `ID`, and it'll return it's ranking by the PTS column. For ID 41, it should return 2 as the 2nd best score of that column.

I am not sure what to google for to get an answer. Is there some SQL code that can do this simply? or maybe php? The `RANK` column is overall rank, and `PTS` is the current weekly score so far. There might be up to 2.5 million entries eventually. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get the number of ppl w/ points higher than the given user's
SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM ranks WHERE PTS > (
    SELECT PTS FROM ranks WHERE ID = 41);
```

...though if you are looking to scale this you probably want to reconsider how you are structuring your data.

Comment: Thanks - this is perfect for what I want. I don't need to scale this particular thing as I'm just going to be taking select numbers out for stats purposes so it'll only be me using it. There will be up to 2.5 million entries in the database which is why I need something simple to take out the rank. At the moment, I'm sorting descending then counting manually which just isn't gonna work long term.

Answer (score 2):

try this query:

### Step1:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
id INT(3),
name char(60),
score INT(5)
);

insert into t values(10,"name1",33);
insert into t values(11,"name2",43);
insert into t values(12,"name3",335);
insert into t values(13,"name4",233);
```

### Step2:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, name, id, score from t order by score desc
```

Comment: @joe Thanks.. this works perfectly. I didn't even realise you could do that with SQL.

Comment: @AlexP I'm not sure why he needs to post it here. The fiddle he posted shows all the code.

Comment: @Cully the idea is that others, with the same problem, can get the solution here. This link may not work years from now

Comment: @AlexP i understand your point, fiddle is temporary (maybe) is that what you mean? especially i didn't log in to write/save it

Answer (score 0):

You just put the PTS into an array and create a loop to add the column output.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $num){
    $sum = $sum + $num;
}
return $sum;
```

Comment: check out `array_sum()` - Either way this is would give the total values and the OP wants the `rank` not the total.